# Some parts of String missing - eclipse bug

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to read all the words as a String from the url - http://www.puzzlers.org/pub/wordlists/unixdict.txt

But the outputted String has some part of the strings missing whenever there is a `'`

1. Why I am getting the same.
2. How to avoid the same.

I am getting the same error when using String builder instead of concatenating.

```
public static String getUrlContents(String theUrl) throws IOException {

        URL url = new URL(theUrl);

        URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));

        String line;
        String text = "";

        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

            text += line + " ";
        }

        bufferedReader.close();

        return text;
    }
```

Output:

After ain' huge blank and then continues from 'd anyhow

[image]

and it continues after

[image]

So it's eating up the text between two subsequent `'` and `'`

Looks like the text is there, since when I search for `antony` which is between the blanks the eclipse highlights the word as seen below, but it's not visible on my screen :O

[image]

Comment: Can you provide example of what is `some parts` which are missing?

Comment: I created a test program with the above code and could not reproduce the issue... words with `'` characters printed out just fine.

Comment: I can see all the content in the string `...aileron aim ain't ainu air...`.

Comment: :( why for me then? I am using eclipse

Comment: Yes, it is working for me also....no change in code required...

Comment: First of all....console has buffer limit size...so if it exceeds the size it is not shown(some eclipse console glitch)...can you try by just reading small file with the content that you suppose caused the error...As for me it is working fine and antony is there in my output data...

Comment: I can't reproduce this either. My psychic powers suggests that the apostrophe `'` char is treated as a *comment* within whatever output window that is. If you run it from outside the IDE, it will probably work fine.

Comment: @selbie eclipse is defacto, is there such a bug in it? I am using Version: Mars.1 Release (4.5.1)

Comment: What happens when you run your app outside of Eclipse? For what it's worth, I'm running Netbeans as my IDE.

Comment: @selbie outside eclipse it's fine, tried sublime-text running ok. So we need eclipse experts here.

Comment: Please somebody try this in Eclipse Mars

Comment: This works fine for me on Eclipse Mars.1 (4.5.1) on Mac OS X 10.11.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already answered by `Naruto` that console has buffer size and above that size content is not visible. To check whether your string is correct or not, just copy whole content from console <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and paste in notepad file, I'm sure you will see complete content.

Basically it's not a bug but predefined size of the console, you can change it as well at (`Window > Preferences > Run/Debug > Console`).

Another way is just use ***Fixed Width Console*** and set Max size which is `1000` and you will be able to see the content in the console.

[image]

Comment: Using fixed width things are fine, but if I remove checkbox "Limit Console Output" it still showcases the same missing string.

Comment: It shouldn't be related to fixed width since the output goes blank at ' and reappears at another '